# problemas ao inserir html em um objeto Json Java

Tags: java, json

Ao inserir um conteúdo html dentro de um obj `Json`

Ele está inserindo uma `\` ao lado de todas as barras das tags de fechamento.

exemplo:

```
input: obj.put("html","< head>< / head>"):

output: "< head>< \/ head>"
```

Como posso ignorar e não inserir nada esta barra no `Json`?

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Para que a comunidade possa te ajudar, é importante que se explique detalhadamente o seu problema e mostre o código que você fez. 

Sugiro que leio os artigos: [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e [como realizar uma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Olá não se preocupe com este caracter, ao decodificar o `JSON`o sistema irá remove-lo:

Segue um exemplo em `java`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("head","<head></head>");
        jsonObject.put("body","<body></body>");
        jsonObject.put("script","<script></script>");

        JSONObject novo = new JSONObject(jsonObject.toString());


        System.out.println(novo.get("head"));
        System.out.println(novo.get("body"));
        System.out.println(novo.get("script"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Veja que ele irá imprimir sem o caracter!

Segue um exemplo em `Javascript`, utilizado o resultado montado pelo `java`:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{"head":"<head><\/head>","body":"<body><\/body>","script":"<script><\/script>"}' );
alert( obj.head);
alert( obj.body);
alert( obj.script);
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Aqui também o caracter é removido!